# NextJS / Sanity Fetch Logs

Tags: next.js, fetch-api, sanity

I keep getting verbose console output when using Sanity's `fetch()` function (from `createClient` in `next-sanity`) like so:

```
export async function getPeople(): Promise<Person[]> {
  return createClient(clientConfig).fetch(
    groq`*[_type == "person"] | order(priority asc, lastName asc){
     ...
    }`
  );
}
```

Logs look like this:

```
-  ┌ GET /research/publications 200 in 740ms
   │
   ├──── GET https://...apicdn.../v2023-07-07/data/query/..?query=*%5B_type.. 200 in 284ms (cache: MISS)
   │
   ├── 1 level ── GET https://...apicdn.../v2023-07-07/data/query/..?query=array%3A%.. 200 in 113ms (cache: MISS)
   │
   ├── 1 level ── GET https://...apicdn.../v2023-07-07/data/query/..?query=array%3A%.. 200 in 68ms (cache: MISS)
   │
   ├── 1 level ── GET https://...apicdn.../v2023-07-07/data/query/..?query=array%3A%.. 200 in 78ms (cache: MISS)
   │
   └── 1 level ── GET https://...apicdn.../v2023-07-07/data/query/..?query=array%3A%.. 200 in 71ms (cache: MISS)
```

People over at the Sanity community suggest its a NextJS thing.

Any help on how to disable them is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone stumbling across this, the issue was resolved by updating packages `next`, `next-sanity`, and `sanity`.